# Bind different kinds of objects containing lists of other objects to a TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview

Hello im new to WPF and i created a datastructure and i want to show my different kind of objects in a TreeView and im a little confused where to begin and how.

This is what my datastructure looks like:

```
    public class Product {
        public int ID;
    }

   public class ProductType1 : Product {
        public double Length;
        public List<Profile> Profiles = new List<Profile>();
        public List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
   }
```

There can be more Product Types, but they are very diffrent and just have a ID in common. And only one at the same time should be loadable in the TreeView.

```
   public class Profile {
        public String Name;
        public List<Rectangles> Rectangles = new List<Rectangles>();
   }

   public class Rectangle {
         public double K1;
         public double K2;
   }

   public class Item {
         public String Name;
         public String Color;
   }
```

Later the TreeView should look like this:

```
-ProductName
--Type: ProductType1
--ID: 1234
--Length: 5000

-Items
--Item1
--Item2
---Colour: blue

-Profiles
--Profile1
--Profile2
---Rectangle1
----K1: 55
----K2: 80
```

My Questions now are:

1.How do i realize the data binding when i want to display ProductType1. I read sth. about HierarchicalDataTemplates. What would the XAML looks like especially the  and the TreeView Binding Part. Do i need extra ViewModels ?

2.How do i realize the data binding in combination with the different Product Types which have just the ID in common. Do i need different DataTemplates for each product and how do i select them.

I hope you can help me and provide me some helpful links!

Comment: I can't give you the solution right now, but let me tell you TreeViews are a huge thing to tackle as a WPF beginner... Also, you will need a viewmodel and a view (UserControl) per model class (so, per ProductTypeX); having these for Profile, Rectangle and Item would be a plus.

Comment: It's not true that you *need* a UserControl per model class. A DataTemplate is usually sufficient. Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: Thank you i'll have a look at it. If you have another useful guides especially for learning wpf and databinding just let me know.

Comment: The [Support for Hierarchical Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview#support-for-hierarchical-data) section in that article might be particularly helpful.